# Can a perturbation of a matrix product always be represented as product of perturbations of its factor matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, perturbation-theory, perturbation

Given $A=BC$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and for some $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}, C\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$. We assume that $k>=\min(m,n)$ so that this decomposition always exists for any matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}.$

Can we prove that any perturbation $\bar{A}$ of $A$ can be represented as the product of two perturbations of $B$ and $C$ ?

Intuitively i think it should be possible but i cannot prove/disprove it. If not possible then what conditions are needed?

Comment: The way you phrased it, I understand that you are trying to prove that, given $\tilde A$ there exist $\tilde B$ and $\tilde C$ such that $$A+\epsilon \tilde A= (B+\epsilon \tilde B)(C+\epsilon \tilde C).$$While this is true to first order in $\epsilon$, with $\tilde A = B\tilde C + \tilde B C$, it is not true in general. Anyway, I don't know if I correctly interpreted the question; I guess not.

Comment: a perturbation here means, for instance, $||\bar{A}-A|| < \epsilon$ for some norm and arbitrary $\epsilon>0.$ So given $\epsilon>0$ and a matrix $\bar{A}$ satisfying $||\bar{A}-A|| < \epsilon$, can we find two matrices $\bar{B},\bar{C}$ so that $\bar{A}=\bar{B} \bar{C}$ and one can bound the distances $||\bar{B}-B||$ and $||\bar{C}-C||$ in terms of $\epsilon$ ? sorry for any confusion.

Comment: The two matrices $\tilde{B}$ and $\tilde{C}$ can surely be found since in the given hypothesis any matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (and so in particular $\tilde{A}$) can be written in the form $\tilde{B}\tilde{C}$. So the real question is on the bound.

Comment: @domenico fiorenza: exactly! The hard part is to show that $\bar{B},\bar{C}$ can be also chosen to be sufficiently close to $B,C$ as $\bar{A}$ is sufficiently close to $A.$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The condition you want is exactly that the matrix multiplication map be locally open at the pair $(B,C)$.  This is the topic of the recent paper [Where is matrix multiplication locally open?](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379516306036) by Behrends.  The paper contains a complete characterization in Theorem 2.5.  According to that theorem, if we let $s$ and $t$ be the ranks of $B$ and $C$, respectively, and let $t = t_1 + t_2$ where $t_1 = \dim (\operatorname{range} C \cap \ker B)$, then matrix multiplication is open at $(B,C)$ iff $t_2\leq k-m$ or $n-t_1\leq k-s$.

Comment: My impression is that the question asks for more than a topological information. For instance, when $n=m=k=1$ consider $B=C=0$. Then the image of the neighborhood $|\tilde{B}|,|\tilde{C}|<\epsilon$ of $(0,0)$ via the multiplication contains an open neighborhood of $0$. But how big? This clearly is $|\tilde{A}|<\epsilon^2$. That is, if we choose an arbitary $\tilde{A}$ with $|\tilde{A}|<\epsilon<1$, we can surely write $\tilde{A}=\tilde{B}\tilde{C}$, with $|\tilde{B}|,|\tilde{C}|<\delta_\epsilon$ for some $\delta_\epsilon$, but we need $\delta_\epsilon\geq\sqrt{\epsilon}>\epsilon$.

Comment: so i guess the real question is: can an a priori bound $\delta_{B,C,|\tilde{A}-BC|}$ in terms of $B,C$ and $|\tilde{A}-BC|$ given such that there exist $\tilde{B}$ and $\tilde{C}$ with $\tilde{B}\tilde{C}=\tilde{A}$ and $|\tilde{B}-B|,|\tilde{C}-C|<\delta_{B,C,|\tilde{A}-BC|}$

Comment: Given that the OP only asked for two perturbations and in the comments only asked to bound their distance from $B$ and $C$ in terms of $\epsilon$ without specifying any particular desired dependence, it seemed reasonable to interpret the question topologically.  But I'll let the OP clarify if he wants something stronger.  It's also possible that a quantitative bound could be extracted from the paper, but I have not read it in detail.

Comment: I think this has been almost the answer. Since it turns out that there always exist a sufficiently small perturbation $A'$ of $A$ such that the corresponding matrices $B'$ and $C'$ can always be chosen within any arbitrary small neighborhood of $B$ and $C.$ But this does not mean that any perturbation of $A$ would directly imply an upper-bound on perturbation of $B$ and $C.$
Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 3):

In numerical analysis lingo, you are more or less asking if matrix multiplication is [backward stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability). The answer seems to be no: see [Section 3.5](https://books.google.it/books?id=7J52J4GrsJkC&lpg=PR2&dq=accuracy%20and%20stability%20of%20numerical%20algorithms&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Higham, *Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms*. I am unable to locate an explicit counterexample quickly, though.