# Perturbation of a rank-restricted product of matrices

Tags: matrices, perturbation-theory, perturbation

I formulated a statement, which is hopefully true (at least I'm not knowledgeable enough to see a reason for it not to be). However, I'm struggling to come up with a proof.

Let $W_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d_i \times d_{i - 1}}, \ i = 1, 2, \ d := \min d_i$. Consider $R := W_2 W_1$ with $\textrm{rank}(R) \leq d$.

> Can we obtain any matrix close to $R$ and of rank not larger than that of $R$ by small perturbations of the factors $W_j$?

More formally, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Can we then find a $\delta>0$ such that for any $P$ with $\|P-R\|<\delta$ and $\textrm{rank}(P) \leq d$, there are $V_i$ such that $V_2V_1=P$ and $\|V_i-W_i\|<\epsilon$?

Does the statement seem correct to you? How could I prove it? Thank you.

Comment: The definition of perturbation is not clear at all (unless you use non-standard matrices, but I guess that you do not.)

Comment: @FedorPetrov, I'm sorry for a possible confusion. Dr. Remling is correct, I would like all $\tilde{W}_j$ to be "close" to $W_j$. What would be the correct way to state this?

Comment: @ChristianRemling, I do agree that the original statement could have been formulated for just two factors. However, I meant "how should a formulate what a perturbation means".

Comment: It's not identical, but see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264606/can-a-perturbation-of-a-matrix-product-always-be-represented-as-product-of-pertu/264658#264658

Comment: @ChristianRemling, thank you, it does seem more coherent.